# Mod_Rewrite Trailing Slash Issue Problem/Question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to lock a client out of a PHP application I created them but, still allow them a "virtual" access to the doc root using:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ftp/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ftp/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) /ftp/$1 [L]
```

This works like a charm when a user goes to: `http://domain.com/dir/`, but going to `http://domain.com/dir` causes a the browser url field to display a `http://domain.com/ftp/dir/` which makes me sad.

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slash from the RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) ftp/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules that might be causing the issue?  Is the file your redirecting to a dynamic file that might be doing a redirect it self? I set up a test environment and your rules seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be caused by [*DirectorySlash*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). Try to disable it.

Comment: Interesting, when turned DirectorySlash is turned off, the redirect works but DirectoryIndex is being ignored. Any idea on a solution to this?

Cheers